# What are the uses of Helical Wheel Projections in Structural Biology?

Tags: molecular-biology, structural-biology

I have seen helical wheel projections used to illustrate amphipathic helices in proteins.  Are there any other uses for these models?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! The first part of your question is opinion based (what does often mean) and thus is not appropriate for this site — in addition it is not clear how knowing the frequency of this type of diagram is helpful. The second part of your question seems more appropriate for bioinformatics.stackexchange.com since it is a technical rather than biological question. ——— Please take the time to check out the tour: biology.stackexchange.com/tour and then the help pages on how to ask questions on this site: biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. Thanks! 

Comment: I agree with @tyersome — it’s a better fit for SE Bionformatics, especially if you ask more precise questions eg for a program that will generate them.

Comment: Apologies. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

[Helical wheel projections](http://www.bioinfo.org.cn/lectures/index-7.html) can be useful anytime you have a protein or peptide with one or more α-helical regions. They allow you to see whether any "property" is present along one side of a peptide. This can be useful in recognizing potential protein-protein interacting motifs such as [leucine zippers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leucine_zipper).

The [wikipedia article on "Helical wheels"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helical_wheel) also looks like a good place to start learning more about this.

Comment: Sounds like the questions is asking for uses besides this one.